# What's the appropriate reaction to an answer that doesn't attribute the source it's copied from?

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution

I was searching through StackOverflow, and found a question with one answer. I found the text of the answer very familiar, and realized it was a direct copy and paste from my blog, with no attribution as to the source.

Naturally I'm happy that people think my writing is helpful, I'd like credit for my copy. I'm not sure what the protocol is. Should I directly ask the user (first answer they've submitted) to update the answer to include a link? Should I report it somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two options really:

1. Flag for moderation attention. State the concern you have over the copyright. A moderator will come along and delete the answer there on the spot.
2. Add a note of attribution, with a link back to the source.

The second option is preferred when you are certain the source allows for their content to be copied across.

Usually this is not the case and the first option is most likely going to happen.